# OutOfMemoryException paging 150K rows using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, out-of-memory

I'm paging 150k rows in pages of 10,000. I mean I bring 10k rows of the database and iterate over them and then the next 10k and do the same until there aren't more rows. The problem is as I bring more rows I see the memory graph increasing in the performance tab of the task manager and in each iteration to bring the 10k rows the query execution last longer and longer until throws an OutOfMemoryException.

The query is a join of 6 tables. I load the results in a list using EF 4.

Al the end of each iteration I clear the list, set it to null and call GC.Collect() but this doesn't have any effect.

What can I make to free memory of the rows I already checked.

Comment: Release the object at line 243...

Comment: Have you disconnected the entity objects from the EF context? By default EF keeps a reference so it can detect changes.

Comment: I avoid using the EF for bulk data loading.  We had a WPF application that was a log file viewer and merely executing the query once ate all available memory.  Using ADO it reduced the memory footprint by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is caused by holding the same context instance to fetch all the pages. In this way, even though you no longer need previously fetched context still keep track of all of them.

You should create new DbContext instance before fetching new batch of records.

You could also try using [`AsNoTracking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx) method.

Comment: I believe the AsNoTracking() function only became available in EF4.1.   @user3891375 could also try to update to a newer version of EF as optimisations have taken place which help to reduce memory load. However this option may not be available to you. The current EF version is 6.0.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem I changed it and put the context in an using inside the for loop that brings the rows.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a very similar issue when attempting return large datasets from a database.

By executing the query from a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) it removed the load from the UI thread, thus reducing the complexity of the task and eliminate this issue.

Before using this technique for my query I saw that application go from a few hundred MB's to top out at about 1.2GB before throwing the OutOfMemoryException. After implimenting the BackgroundWorkder the increase would only be about 10/15mb, then reduce back down once it had completed. I would also suggest the query executed slightly faster.

-Yes, I realise that this doesn't sound like it would work, but it actually did and I would recommend it.

Additionally if you were running on a 64bit OS (and targeting  64 bit architecture) you could raise the memory limit from 1.2GB to 4GB. This option can be found in the Project Properties under the Build tab...

Depending on the DB, you may be able to shift some of the work off to it by creating a view and querying that to gather your result set. (- Update)